# calculate overlap in R

Tags: r, function, overlap

:)
I am using R and I have several file, each of those are like this:

```
  ID_A ID_B
  1   AA
  2   AB
  3   AA
  1   AF
  5   AA
  6   AB
 ...  ...
```

I don't know in advance how many ID are presented in each file (the amounts changed in each file), the column are always the same.
I would like to calculate the overlap among ID_A and ID_B and obtained a file like this:

```
12356 0
1235  0
1236  0
1356  0
1256  0
...   ...
123   0
156   0
135   AA
235   0
236   0
...   ...
13    AA
26    AB
...  ...
```

Therefore, what I would like to obtained is the output of the function:

> calculate.overlap

of R. But the problem is to "traduce" the names of the object reported in the output list(a1,a2,a3...).

I have already read this post: [The output order of function calculate.overlap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37450698/the-output-order-of-function-calculate-overlap)

But I didn't understand how fix the problem... I am wondering if exist another solution or another function that can help me.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution: using gplot package and with this command it is possibile to obtained the intersection with the "name":

```
library(gplots) 
output <- venn(data=file_list,show.plot = FALSE)
```

Comment: This is the best answer I have found yet.