# How to find which elements related to which parts of venn diagram using calculate.overlap function in r?

Tags: r, dataframe, overlapping, venn-diagram

The output of calculate.overlap is not clear.
There are some names for each position of venn diagram such as: $a1 , $a2 , ...
It becomes so complicated when we draw it for five list.
How to recognize which names ($a1 , $a2 , ...) related to the overlap of which lists?

```
library(VennDiagram)

overlap=calculate.overlap(
    x=list(
        "A"=c("a","b","c"),
        "B"=c("a","b","c","d"),
        "C"=c("a","c","d")
    )
)
```

and this is the output:

```
$a5
[1] "a" "c"

$a2
[1] "b"

$a4
character(0)

$a6
[1] "d"

$a1
character(0)

$a3
character(0)

$a7
character(0)
```

How to replace these names with the names of my list?

My expected output is:

```
$A,B,C
[1] "a" "c"

$A,B
[1] "b"

$A,C
character(0)

$B,C
[1] "d"

$A
character(0)

$B
character(0)

$C
character(0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37450698/the-output-order-of-function-calculate-overlap). However, I do not claim to understand it. The general rule to order the regions in a Venn diagram is to use a binary representation of it. My `nVennR` package uses that representation and can give you a quick answer for any number of sets:

```
> library(nVennR)
> myV <- plotVenn(list("A"=c("a","b","c"), "B"=c("a","b","c","d"), "C"=c("a","c","d")), showPlot = F)
> listVennRegions(myV)
$`0, 1, 1 (B, C)`
[1] "d"

$`1, 1, 0 (A, B)`
[1] "b"

$`1, 1, 1 (A, B, C)`
[1] "a" "c"

> listVennRegions(myV, na.rm = F)
$`0, 0, 0 ()`
[1] NA

$`0, 0, 1 (C)`
[1] NA

$`0, 1, 0 (B)`
[1] NA

$`0, 1, 1 (B, C)`
[1] "d"

$`1, 0, 0 (A)`
[1] NA

$`1, 0, 1 (A, C)`
[1] NA

$`1, 1, 0 (A, B)`
[1] "b"

$`1, 1, 1 (A, B, C)`
[1] "a" "c"
```

There is a [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/nVennR/vignettes/nVennR.html) with more details on usage.